# Why only some .webp images do not render in browser?

Tags: html, webp

At the outset let me clear that the only other relevant question on stack overflow [Chrome only displaying some images as webp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626879/chrome-only-displaying-some-images-as-webp) has no solution.

So explaining my situation

I have the following HTML code

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="<?php echo $woeim;?>.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="<?php echo $woeim;?>.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <source srcset="<?php echo $woeim;?>.png" type="image/png">
  <img src="<?php echo $tmpimg;?>">
</picture>
```

The folder referred for images contain webp version of image for all image types in the folder created with PHP's following functions

> imagecreatefrom()
> imagewebp()

And all webp version of the existing png images have been created and are showing thumbnails in the folder

However, when trying to display the images with the above HTML code, only some images are rendered in the browser - though all of the webp images exist in the folder

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows 5 errors in the console, are they related? And is there any pattern to which images don't work? (E.g. images with symbols in the file name or capitalisation in the file extension, etc)

Comment: @DBS The errors are not related to this. However, some images are being displayed while others aren't. Even if you click from the images folder, some open some don't. All have similar naming nomenclature